# Hide outer div if inner div is empty

Tags: css

I would like to hide my outer div if price div is empty using just css. Can u help?

```
<div class="pricetag"> Hello
    <div class="price">400</div>
</div>

<div class="pricetag"> Hello2
    <div class="price"></div>
</div>

<div class="pricetag"> Hello3
    <div class="price">250</div>
</div>
```

Comment: On top of the duplication, you can't read the contents of an element with css. You'd need javascript.

Comment: If the price div is empty, is it still present as an empty div, or is it not display? What you are asking may not be possible with just CSS. EDIT: nvm, this is evident from your sample code. I think you will need JS.

Comment: When the :has() pseudo-class becomes available you can do what you are trying to do using CSS